# Destructuring Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program where I have a dictionary with only one key and one value, I want to store key in a key variable and value in a value variable

**here's my code**

```
def add(self, data, unique=False):
        content = self.readfile()
        if unique:
            for dictionary in content:
                key,value = dictionary
                print(key, value)
                try:
                    if(data[unique] == value[unique]):
                        return 'Data Exist'
                except:
                    pass
```

**structure of content**

```
[
    {'1': 'Value'},
    {'2': 'Value'},
    {'3': 'Value'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the list of dictionaries in your data list, then append the keys and values in each of the dictionaries in the list to keys, and values variables respectively.

```py
data=[
    {'1': 'Value1'},
    {'2': 'Value2'},
    {'3': 'Value3'}
]

keys, values = [], []
for d in data:
    for k,v in d.items():
        keys.append(k)
        values.append(v)
print(keys, values)

# Output: ['1', '2', '3'] ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing about variables to notice is when you declare the same variable twice or more, the last data goes to it is the value of the variable itself.

In you case you want to make a variable from the key and distinguish that it’s a key and the same to the value.

There’re two approaches for solving this kind of problems, first one is to used a ready exist library that makes a Json object for the Dict/Json and make instances variables for the keys, values pairs.

lets assume data is a variable with the Dict

```
from JsonDF.utils.Json.Json import Json

json = Json(‘data’, data)
print(json.1)

# outputs : value
```

Install it with `pip install JsonDF`

In this code every key is an instance variable with its value to it, the package supposed nested dict also.

The second approach which is not really the right approach to go with, in fact there is a lot of warnings and dangers to work with this approach, is to use `globals()` but the first approximation is more safe.

The code will be like the following :

```
for key, value in data.items():
    globals()[f”key_{key}”] = value
```

Feel free to comment if there’s any problems.